# What is the name of the role that allows one to use oc/kubectl port-forward?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-security

I'd like to create a Service Account which is allowed to do `oc port-forward` on OpenShift.com Online (AKA `kubectl port-forward` on Kubernetes), but can't for the life of me figure out which of the many roles I see in `oc get clusterrole` would permit that? (`oc get role` is empty.)

```
error: error upgrading connection: pods "minecraft-storeys-maker-40-ps85h" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:learn-study:oc-port-forward-container" cannot create pods/portforward in the namespace "learn-study": User "system:serviceaccount:learn-study:oc-port-forward-container" cannot create pods/portforward in project "learn-study"
```

So based on this error message I've tried "pods/portforward", but no good:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user pods/portforward -z oc-port-forward-container
Error from server (BadRequest): Name parameter invalid: "pods/portforward": may not contain '/'
```

Also just "portforward" is no good:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user portforward -z oc-port-forward-container 
Error from server (NotFound): rolebindings.authorization.openshift.io "portforward" not found
```

It's for https://github.com/OASIS-learn-study/oc-port-forward-container.

Comment: From memory I know a user needs at least ``edit`` role in a project. I don't know if there is a more fine grained role you can add to a non user service account to allow it.

Comment: `pods/portforward` is the name of a resource within k8s RBAC, not a role. you need a role with create permissions on `pods/portforward` resources.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenShift the `edit` and `admin` cluster roles should have `create` permissions on `pods/portforward`.

Therefore, a command such as `oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z <your-sa-name>` should add the permissions you need.